# Copy File: Name Contains Spaces

Tags: shell, unix, copy, solaris

I have a large shell script that processes files each of my Solaris systems.

In the beginning the script creates a variable FILENAME
Sometimes people create directories/files that contain spaces.
e.g.

```
/users/ldap/Anukriti's System Backup/BACKUP/workspace/BP8/scripts/yui/editor/simpleeditor.js
```

Later in the script I run

```
cp $FILENAME $DESTDIR/
```

As you can imagine this always fails because the following is invalid.

```
cp /users/ldap/Anukriti's System Backup/BACKUP/workspace/BP8/scripts/yui/editor/simpleeditor.js $DESTDIR
```

I have tried putting the Variable in Quotes, but this is not working. I have used find with -exec option before, but for this circumstance that is not really an option, especially since Solaris does not support the -wholename or -path options

What can i do here?

Comment: Please add `echo cp "$FILENAME" "$DESTDIR"`  before invoking the copy, change the cp line to `cp "$FILENAME" "$DESTDIR"` and post the output

Comment: Results from `echo cp "$FILENAME" "$DESTDIR"` . `cp /users/ldap/Anukriti's System Backup/BACKUP/workspace/BP8/scripts/yui/editor/simpleeditor.js /mnt/nastmp/dev/oscar/`

Comment: For some reason you are resisting posting the error message, without which it is very difficult to know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Give us the last few lines of `sh -x /path/to/bigscript`

Comment: @MiserableVariable `cp: cannot stat Backup/BACKUP/workspace/BP8/scripts/yui/editor/simpleeditor.js: No such file or directory`

Comment: @nitrobass24, is there another errors above in your output ?

Comment: @sputnick nope that is the only error

Comment: So your path is wrong, you lack the start of the file path.

Comment: @sputnick I know...its because of the space...hence the reason i posted this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like i need to use curly braces for variable expansion and double Quotes

```
cp "${FILENAME}" $DESTDIR
```

Comment: That's not the real answer and not your problem. Using braces makes no difference in this case. Braces only matter if the variable name is followed by alphanumeric characters, as in `echo "${FOO}BAR"` vs `echo $FOOBAR`.

Comment: Well it works, thats all I can say compared to the other answers

Answer (score 9):

You just have to protect the variables with quotes :

```
cp "$FILENAME" "$DESTDIR"
```

**NOTE**

Don't use single quotes `'`, the variables can't be expanded this way.

Comment: You say "see above" but haven't provided any other info besides "this is not working".

Comment: The last line in the OP says I tried putting the Variable in Quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

- `$DESTDIR` exists
- is a directory
- and yes, use double quotes for both variables and get rid of the trailing `/`.

You might not believe it, but that is your problem. :-)

Comment: It does exist because it works everytime, the source file doesnt have a space.

Comment: Right, and the solution to deal with spaces is using double quotes, nothing else. If that doesn't fix your problem, you're not telling us everything we need to know. Is the `cp` command part of an `eval` in the big script?

Comment: No the rest of the script is irrelevant. Make a file "my file". Then set it as a variable. `FILENAME="my file"` . Then run `echo cp $FILENAME /destdir/` ... output is `cp my file /destdir/` .. which is not valid because of the spaces... if you run `cp my file /destdir/` the output is `cp: cannot stat file: No such file or directory` ... OK lets add Quotes `cp "$FILENAME" /destdir/` ... Same results  `cp: cannot stat file: No such file or directory` ...